# Display parsed data to user in input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am not sure i have this right.  maybe someone can assist me on this.

i am working inside of a text box element that is preprogrammed within the site.  in the element, i need it to parse the date from element 380 and then count the number of days from todays date to the parsed date, then display the number of days as text.  the displayed text must be uneditable to the user.

I have tried multiple different types of code and looked up every different element to get this right and i am still simply stuck on this.  here is a copy of the cod ethat i place inside the input element:

```
<script>

<readonly>
  
$(function() {
var dateData = $('#data_380_1').html(); 
var date = Date.parse(dateData);
var today = Date.now();
var numberOfDays = Math.abs(Math.floor((today - date) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24));

</script>
<form action = value = numberofdays>
```

the overall part of the project is to display to the user the number of days from "todays" date to the date they select in element 380 on the form.  with that information, they can then select the correct option to move forward.

Comment: Will the textbox element (where you input your code) execute your code? What additional syntax does it allow, if any? Will it only execute JS, or also do something with the HTML bits your code contains?

Comment: Your JS and HTML seem to have some issues, e.g. `<readonly>` is not valid JS; your jQuery function isn't closed; and only `value` will be the attribute `action`'s value, the following `=` will be invalid HTML, and I guess `numberofdays` will be a separate (but unknown) attribute.

Comment: @OskarGrosser, generally, the form updates in real time when  the user navigates through it.  but it there is a code way of telling it to execute once the user enters data , that would be helpful.

I know that the code has holes in it, i have tried to piece it together with snips i am finding by a google search.  i thought i coded the variables correctly, but i cant figure out how to tell the code to enter the value of the information into the text box once the user enters the date in the text box before this one.

Comment: can I give the solution in Vanilla JS or does it needs to be JQuery?

Comment: @HindSagarBiswas i am willing to try anything!

Comment: @Tony I gave the answer with both vanilla and jquery and fixed the problems, tell me if it does not solve the problem, else accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So let's approach the solution in steps:

1. We add an event listener to the input of date so that, it can update the remaining days whenever we select a date.
2. On change -> take the value from input, parse it and set the value to the output
3. Since we want the output to be readonly, there are 2 ways to do that:

   1. To use a input with `readonly` attribute [let's use this for now]
   2. To use a `div` or `p` etc that can't be edited

### CODE

#### Vanilla:

```js
const dateInput = document.querySelector('#input-date');
const dateOutput = document.querySelector('#output-date');

function setNumOfDays(e) {
  const today = Date.now();
  let date = Date.parse(dateInput.value);
  let numberOfDays = Math.abs(Math.ceil((today - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
  dateOutput.value = numberOfDays;
}

dateInput.addEventListener('change', setNumOfDays)
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="date" id="input-date">
      <input type="text" name="" id="output-date" readonly>
</form>
```

#### jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const dateInput = $('#input-date');
  const dateOutput = $('#output-date');

  function setNumOfDays() {
    const today = Date.now();
    const date = Date.parse(dateInput.val());
    const numberOfDays = Math.abs(Math.ceil((today - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    dateOutput.val(numberOfDays);
  }

  dateInput.on('change', setNumOfDays);
});
```

**NOTE:** I have fixed your algorithm to find date using `.ceil()` instead of `.floor()`. The previous one gave 1 day more than the actual, e.g. if selected date is tomorrow, it gave 2 instead of 1.